# ffmpeg loudnorm filter without target range

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use ffmpeg's loudnorm filter to standardise a batch of films to the same loudness level.

My target is: integrated loudness -23 LUFS, max true peak -1 dB.

The intention is to bring all the films to the same loudness level, and to limit any high peaks which would go above 0 dB (and so distort) if you just turn up the gain.

For example, if the input file is -28 LUFS, but true peak at -2 dB: to get the desired effect, it needs limiting to -6 dB first and then gain of +5 dB.

From my understanding, this is exactly what the loudnorm filter is designed to do.

However, the trouble I am having is that loudnorm also mandates providing a target loudness range (or uses a default value, if you don't provide one).

In my case, I don't care about the loudness range. Some files will have higher dynamic range than others, and that's fine. I just want to target integrated loudness and max true peak. But I can't avoid loudnorm also taking target range into account.

I have tried using various range values.

- High loudness range value doesn't increase the LUFS, as it appears to prioritise preserving a wide range.
- Low range value achieves the desired LUFS and max true peak, but often goes beyond that and heavily compresses dynamic range.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What is your present command?